# Recursively copy files that match a wildcard combination but not create the directory tree in DOS

Tags: recursion, copy, dos, xcopy

I found that I can use `xcopy /s` to copy all files that match a wildcard combination in a folder to another location. But this command re-creates the folder structure. I do not want the tree. I need just the files dumped into the destination folder. There are no duplicate files in the source folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `for` command:

```
for /R %%x in (*.cpp) do copy "%%x" "c:\dest\"
```

If you want to run it directly from command prompt (not from a batch file) use %x instead of %%x.

Answer (score 2):

For your purpose, instead of using xcopy you should use robocopy:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Robocopy seems to have a lot more options than xcopy. I didn't realise that it was a MS utility. Anyway, the command option to make look recursively says "Copies directories..."